# nginx 404 logs to all virtualhosting logs

Tags: nginx, logging, http-status-code-404

I am using nginx and i have two sites running:

site1 = /1/access.log
site2 = /2/access.log

when a user get 404 images not found on site2 nginx writes to access.log of site1 & site2 reporting the not found error, i tried everything to get separated logs without luck, i want everything that happen on site1 logged on /1/access.log and everything that happens on site2 logged on /2/access.log

any help ?

Comment: Can you post your configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of nginx are you  using ?

Newer version has /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf files where you can mention following parameter for each of your site.

access_log  /path/to/access.log
error_log  /path/to/error.log

Make sure these are set on per *.conf basis.